# How can I modify a transition for an already existing work item?

Tags: workitem, tfs-workitem

I recently started as a TFS administrator for a company that has been using TFS 2010 for a while.

We have a specific work item (We'll call it #123) that is stuck in a State (Re-opened) that can't be changed (no other options in the drop-down besides "Re-opened").  I am trying to figure out a way to close this particular work item (Change the status to "Closed"), but my Google searches keep bringing me up information about how to modify the Work Item Template, which I already know how to do.

The latest version of the template that's been imported into that particular Team Project contains a valid transition out of the "Re-opened" state to "Closed" for the group I am part of, and it works properly for all other work items in that Team Project.

So, the question of the day is, how can I close this work item?  Is there a way to modify the transitions for it, or a commandline utility that'll let me force a change in the state for just this one work item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by removing my group from the Project Administrators group and then adding it back in again.
I'm not sure why it worked, I'm just glad it did.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to open TFS in TFS Web Application, Right click on work item and Click Edit,
Observe a Pop up with title "Edit Work Item" is displaying. Select "State" in Field and Select the "State" Value in the next text field. Click Ok. Please try this and let me know.

Comment: From the query, I don't have any right-click options that are relevant to the TFS web access, however under the Tools button, there's a "Bulk Edit Selected Work Items" which has a screen similar to the one you described.  It looks like it might work, when my boss comes in I'll find out what state she wants me to put it in and let you know if it works!

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work, it made me open up the work item, and there it had the error that I was trying to change the Status to an invalid value (Since the only thing in the list is the current status).

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you are facing is because the Status of the Work Item is related in one way to other Status. So you are not able to Change the Status. So we Can provide the Status with new relation, with below steps, or editing the WIT files.

Open the Visual Studio, Go to Tools>> Go to Process Editor>> Go To Work Items>> Open WIT from Server>> Select Server>> Select Work Item Type>> Edit the Status present. For Example: If "Removed" is the Status present currently, Add a relation to the Current Status as, For example "new". (Per your Boss's request) you can change the relations of the Status.

Comment: If by "relations" you mean a transition from one state to another, we already have one out of that state to a valid state, and it works for all other work items in that Team Project, but not that specific work item.  I will edit my question to make that more clear.